# Spring Security + Thymeleaf - TemplateInputException after a second login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a navbar with **LOGIN**, **PROFILE**, and **LOGOUT**.
My goal is to remove the LOGIN and show only PROFILE and LOGOUT
after the user is logged in.
I have the controller checking for authenticated users:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    private String loginRender(){
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken){
            return "login";
        }else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
}
```

The Thymeleaf template looks like this:

```
<ul class="logout-ul top-links-container">
    <li class="top-links-item  text-center" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()"><a href="/login"> <i class="icon-user4" style="color: #e35f5f"></i>Login</a></li>
    <li class="top-links-item text-center" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a href="/user/profile"><i class="icon-user4" style="color: #e35f5f"></i>Profile</a></li>
    <li class="text-center logout" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><form th:action="@{/logout}" th:method="post"><button title="LOGOUT" class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-off"></i></button></form></li>
</ul>
```

Configuration:

```
 http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/", "register",
                    "/custom-transfers/**", "/about-us", "/information/**", "/support/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole(UserRoleEnum.ADMIN.name())
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
          .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY)
                .passwordParameter(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY)
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/profile")
                //TODO validation page
                .failureForwardUrl("/login")
          .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
```

**ISSUE**
It all works when the user first logs in. When logouts and log in again, Thymleaf shows a TemplateInputException.

Exception:

```
ERROR 26304 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/login] and exception [An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/login.html]")] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/login.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
```

I tried placing sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" outside in a `<div>`, tried to pass a `boolean` to the template with a `RedirectAttribute` and `Model`, but I can't still fix the issue.
It works when I add:
`<li class="top-links-item" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">TEST</li>`
so I assume is because I use `sec:authorize` for a login page, which is managed by Spring Security. Could there be any relation?

**UPDATE** I found that after logout the Cookie destroys and it doesn't creates a new one for a second login. Also the issue is only of logout form in the html when I add `sec:authorize=isAuthenticated()`. Therefore the problem is connected to the logout instead of the login page. Why could this happen?

This occurs only when I use `isAuthenticated()` in Thyemleaf.

What am I doing wrong?
I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you have shared and I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. A couple of hints, make sure you are setting `xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` in the HTML files and including the dependency `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thank you for your answer. Yes, the dependency and the Thymeleaf tag are set, but the problem appears only when I "hide and show" the logout `<li>` line. Currently, the logout button is always visible for all users, and there is no problem, but I can't hide it for the logged ones. Do you have any idea where else could potentially be the problem?

Comment: I was thinking if Spring Security prevents hiding the form with csrf token, but it doesn't seem accurate.

Comment: Try simplifying the configuration to narrow down the issue. What happens if you have a single Thymeleaf template for the login page? What happens if you remove the logic from the "/login" endpoint and simply return the page?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I just tried all of that. Removed the logic from the controller, and returned only the login template, and changed some things in the security configuration, but it still login page brokes with the same error. However, I covered the issue with `th:hidden="${logged}"` and Model in the controller if a user is logged in. It works now, but I still wonder what could be the reason. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what happens here is the following:

Your logout form is managed by Thymeleaf which means that under the hood Thymeleaf will try to create a hidden field with the CSRF token inside. This normally works and it requires existing or new session.

The problem is that Thymeleaf is designed to minimize latencies by producing template output as your template is being processed. Thus when a page is longer in size (as it is in your case) by the time when the engine reaches your logout `<form>` tag some of the output **MAY HAVE BEEN** streamed to the client and the server starts to consider your response as *committed*. Once the response is marked as committed Thymeleaf will fail to access/create a session. I guess this is an architectural constraint.

So I'm not sure what exactly to advise you here. Maybe try to output the logout button earlier in your templates or optionally try to eagerly initialize the CSRF token. This setting in `HttpSecurity` will possibly do it:

```
.and()
   .csrf()
   .csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. `.csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())` really solved the issue.